# Nested UIScrollviews behaving strangely

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have the following autolayout-driven setup:

- Main viewController, with a scrollview inside it. Scrollview pinned to superview edges. This one scrolls up and down.
  A few normal, fixed size views at the top of the scrollview
- Another scrollview. This one scrolls left and right. The second scrollview contains a couple of tableviews, side by side. The idea is that the user can switch between them. They both contain a handful of cells, all the same width as the screen and 72pts tall.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the tableview contents are not the same size. The left one has say, 6 cells, and the right one has 3.

My first approach was to dynamically change the second scrollview height to match which ever tableview was currently visible. What ended up happening was that switching between the two tableviews (by doing setContentOffset:animated:) went extremely wrong if animated was set to true - it would adjust the content offset so everything was offscreen. In fact it would set the content offset to  and then  as I switched, about a dozen times, then it'd reset. It was weird, I gave up.

Now I'm trying to just adjust the content inset of the main scrollview to offset the gap in the content of the current tableview, and it's also being weird. When I set the bottom content inset in viewDidLoad, it works fine. When I set it at the time the tableview becomes current, it does nothing.

What gives? What scenarios would lead to these view interactions not behaving properly?

Comment: The problem, as far as I can see, is mostly that you have not set the contentsize of your scrollView probably. Set first scrollView's contentSize as (view.width, 1000) and second scrollView's contentSize (1000, view.height), and set the tableView's size manually to see if if the problem still persists.. If it doesn't then what is left is to calcuate the contentsize correctly in run time.

Comment: Can you post a sample project which mimics the same behavior that you are facing.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your view hierarchy?

Comment: Also, post the constraints

Comment: can you share your sample code ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you would like to resolve. You may also provide a visual representation of the required implementation i.e. [UI/UX use case](https://uxdesign.cc/ui-ux-case-study-a-step-by-step-guide-to-the-process-of-designing-a-pet-diet-app-d635b911b648) if you feel uncomfortable posting your code. Unfortunately, an effective solution that you can use cannot be created until the root cause is determined. Many individuals on SO are willing to help, if provided with the needed information.

Answer (score 2):

- Use different `tableViewController` for each table.
- Embed them in `pageViewController`.
- Add those few normal, fixed size views at the top of the `pageViewController`s view.
- Conform `scrollViewDelegate` in `pageViewController`.
- Pass `scrollViewDidScroll` from tableViews to `pageViewController`.
- Set tableViews inset to match those fixed size views at top.
- Change height according to the scroll.

This is the way you can achieve the functionality you want.
I hope it helps.